# Using Chrome on mobile device to read HTML files on a PC through USB?

Tags: android, google-chrome, web-applications, adb, mobile-devices

Currently I'm developing a web page application and I would like to test it on my mobile device (Android, to be specific). I need to run it on the actual device, and simply testing it using the emulator on the PC Chrome is not enough. I know how to use ADB to inspect the running result on a PC as I open the URL on my phone, which is very helpful; however, every time I make a change to the web page, I still need to upload the files to a remote server in order for the Chrome on my phone to open it. I wonder if there's a way to use my phone to directly open the HTML file on my PC while they're connected by USB? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found myself asking the same question, and through a little bit of experimentation I have found a solution which works.

First, connect your device as usual like in Angus' answer. The trick is another feature of Chrome's DevTools, port forwarding. Go into the **Remote devices** tab, followed by **Settings**, and tick the box that says **Port forwarding**. I'll use port 8000 for both sides here, but you can change them if you wish. Click **Add rule**, and fill in `8000` for the device port and `localhost:8000` for the local address. Confirm, and your port forward is set up.

As for the server, if you just want a simple directory mirror I recommend using something like [Python's SimpleHTTPServer module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html) (`http.server` in Python 3), which you can run like this from the target directory:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
python3 -m http.server
```

Once you have the server running, you can open a new tab either on your phone or from Chrome with URL `localhost:8000`, or whichever port you used for the device. All the files under this structure will then be available.

Read more: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/local-server

Comment: This is a little different from what I'm expecting, as technically it is still not really "local file access" but uses a HTTP server that happens to be my PC. But it does get the job done for sure.

Comment: If you have Node (after port forwarding), you can do http-server -a localhost -p 8000 and afterwards open the page from your mobile phone plugged in debug mode (localhost:8000/miofile.html). This works for me

Answer (score 0):

The answer : `Chrome’s Remote Debugging`

*Chrome’s Remote debugging* allows you to you connect your computer’s Chrome’s developer tools to your Android device running mobile Chrome. With this you have full access to the Chrome developer tools for your mobile browser!

What you would need:

Chrome Browser on your computer
Chrome mobile running on your Android device (Android 4.0 and above)
USB Cable (and possibly the drivers for your mobile device already installed on your computer)

**Step 1: Find your mobile device using Chrome**

Connect your mobile device to your computer. On your mobile device, go to Settings > Developer options and enable USB Debugging.

Don’t see the developer options? Go to Settings > About phone and tap the Build Number a few times. You should get a prompt with the number of clicks left for you to “become a developer” .

On your computer, fire up Chrome, and then the developer tools (Cmd/Ctrl + Opt/Alt + i). On the row with the different tabs, click on the three dots on the right to load more options. There, under More Tools, you should find an option called Remote Devices.

Plug-in your mobile device to your computer; this would immediately throw an authorization prompt on it. Until you allow this, the device would be in a Pending Authorization state in the dev tools. Click on OK.

Until you confirm, the device is will be in “Pending Authorization” state
The device is now authorized and ready to go! The Chrome developer tools should now list your device name and type.

**Step 2: Inspecting**

Once you’re done setting up, you can now inspect tabs directly on your computer’s Chrome!

Fire up Chrome on your mobile device.
Click on your device name in the chrome developer tools on your computer. It should list the different tabs that you’ve got open on your mobile device. Click on the Inspect button for the tab you want to debug.
Chrome should open up a new window, with a real-time version of your mobile browser’s tab on the left and all your regular developer tools on the right.

And that’s it!

You now have access to all the debugging goodness of the developer tools…now for your mobile device!

Source and tutorial with images: [Debug your website on a mobile device](https://blog.campvanilla.com/debug-website-on-mobile-device-5c27c8809d39)

Comment: Google's documentation on [Chrome Remote Debugging](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/)

Comment: You didn't read through my question; I already know how to use the debug tool but this does not achieve what I need.